# Accessing a function from a pointer via -> syntax c++

Tags: c++

I'm working in a class function:

```
void Planner::CellSort()
{
    vector<vector<int>> *pointer_to_open = &openlist;
    sort(pointer_to_open->begin(), pointer_to_open->end(), Compare);
}
```

When I try to compile it I get the following error:

```
error: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function
```

But When I try the following compile just fine:

```
sort((&openlist)->begin(), (&openlist)->end(), Compare);
```

Isn't both actually doing the same? or what's the difference between those two approaches.

This is my Compare function:

```
bool Planner::Compare(const vector<int> a, const vector<int> b)
{
    int f1 = a[2] + a[3]; // f1 = g1 + h1
    int f2 = b[2] + b[3]; // f2 = g2 + h2
    return f1 > f2;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: can you show the compare function? if the compare function parameters something along the line of const std::vector<int>& a, const std::vector<int>& b, it should work.

Comment: https://ideone.com/Rw93A8 demonstrates how its down using sort(pointer_to_open->begin(), pointer_to_open->end(), Compare);

Comment: also, don't understand why this question marked duplicate with a link to a potential answer. 0.0'. it seems the issue at hand different then whether if a function () has higher precedence then the binding operator...

Comment: @Yucel_K I added the compare function, I check the code it the URL and it seems like mine I still can't figure out why it doesn't compile.

Comment: when you call the compare function, the vectors are passed as copies. instead, they could be passed by reference. that way you don't make a copy of the vectors every time you call the compare function. so you gain a speed advantage.  all you have to do is change compare function. as such; **Compare(const vector<int>& a, const vector<int>& b)** and it should work

Comment: continued: Notice the **&** operator. this basically telling the compiler that compare function is taking the address of the vector as a parameter rather than a copy of the vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `vector<vector<int>> *pointer_to_open = &openlist;`

So, here pointer_to_open has the address of `openlist`. So, if do `*pointer_to_open`, it will point to the value of `openlist`, not `pointer_to_open` (as it has address of openlist).

You are using:

`pointer_to_open` and not `*pointer_to_open`

Consider [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pointers-c-examples/) and [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/begin/) article on pointers and vectors.

What you can do:

```
void Planner::CellSort()
{
    vector<vector<int>> *pointer_to_open = &openlist;
    sort(*pointer_to_open->begin(), *pointer_to_open->end(), Compare);
}
```

It should work as fine as using `&openlist`

Comment: @Steven Daniel Anderson
 is this not an answer? I thought you said that it worked?

Comment: I thought it did, but the same error is happening, I know it should work but it doesn't :/

Comment: What is the error? Same? Can you edit your question with exactly what you have tried?

Comment: When I try your way *pointer_to_open->begin() i got the following: error: no match for 'operator-' (operand types are 'std::vector<int>' and 'std::vector<int>')

Comment: But, `(&openlist)->begin()` is same as `((*pointer_to_open)->begin())` in your case. So, if the first one is working, the later should work just fine.